# Stacking Turn Resistance

Tags: dnd-3.5e, undead

**Does Turn Resistance from different sources stack?**

Typed bonuses do not stack, however, turn resistance doesn't specify a type.  So, if an undead gets a multiple bonuses to turn resistance do they stack or overlap?

The only reference I've been able to find is the feat: *Improved Turn Resistance* which **specifically** states that it stacks.  No other sources I've seen state the type of *bonus* or how it interacts with other bonuses.

I'm surprised this hasn't been asked already (unless it was embedded in another question so I didn't see it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they do. As you say, it is an untyped bonus, which always stack unless they are from the same source (and the primary source of Turn Resistance, Improved Turn Resistance, specifically trumps that general rule).

Comment: I guess the confusion is, if they always stack why would these feats specifically state it (this would infer that without this declaration they would not)?  It never makes a point to say that the normal rules in effect are in effect for other feats.

Comment: The rules are often redundant because human beings are not computers, and don't automatically remember how these things work. And because WotC is just as fallible...

Comment: Impeccable reasoning +1

Comment: I left the answer unaccepted for a day to give time for more responces..apparently the answer is so solid no other answers were warranted.  Thx for the info